# BOX put side by side

Tags: html, css

So the problem is whenever i make the green and orange put side by side it doesn't work even if 1000 divided by 2 is 500(btw new in html)
I really don't know much about positions and sizes in html

Here is the HTML of the whole thing

```css
h1{
        position:relative;
        color:#89CFF0;
        font-family:arial;
        width:1000px;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;  
    }
    .boxes{
        width:1000px;
        margin:0 auto;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #box1{
        font-family:arial;
        border:1px solid red;
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:1000px;
        top:40px;
        background-color:red;
    }
    #box2{
        font-family:arial;
        border:1px solid blue;
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:1000px;
        height:150px;       
        top:40px;
        background-color:blue;
    }

    #box3{
        position:relative;
        font-family:arial;
        border:1px solid green;
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:500px;
        height:100px;
        top:40px;
        float:left;
        background-color:green;
    }

    #box4{
        font-family:arial;
        border:1px solid orange;
        margin:0 auto;
        position:relative;
        width:500px;
        height:100px;
        top:40px;
        float:left;
        background-color:orange;
    }

    #box5{
        font-family:arial;
        border:1px solid yellow;
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:1000px;
        top:140px;
        background-color:yellow;
    }
```

```html
<h1> The Box </h1>
<div class="boxes">
  <div id="box1">
    <p>RED</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <p>BLUE</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
    <p>GREEN</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box4">
    <p>ORANGE</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box5">
    <p>YELLOW</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output:
[image: THIS IS THE PIC]

I think the problem is with the px of the `.box3` and I'm sure that `box5` is good

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the border size as to include in calculation. You have parent div of 1000px. you are dividing divs in 50% as 500px. Now there is a border that you are missing to consider. so 1px border will result in 2px (left + right) of additional width i.e. 502px. so you need to reduce the width by 2px i.e. 498px.

See working snippet here.

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #89CFF0;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.boxes {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#box1 {
  font-family: arial;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  top: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

#box2 {
  font-family: arial;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#box3 {
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 498px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 40px;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

#box4 {
  font-family: arial;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 498px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 40px;
  float: left;
  background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
  font-family: arial;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  top: 140px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1> The Box </h1>
<div class="boxes">
  <div id="box1">
    <p>RED</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    <p>BLUE</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box3">
    <p>GREEN</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box4">
    <p>ORANGE</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box5">
    <p>YELLOW</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add both green and orange in one div

```
  <div id="box3">
      <div>
       <p>GREEN</p>
      <div>
      <div>
       <p>ORANGE</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Add `display:flex` to main div `box3`  it will result in side by side
check the below snippet for the flex property

or you can use the `**Bootstrap Grid**

```css
#boxes{
    display:flex;
 }


#box3{
      background-color:green;
      width:450px;
    }
 #box4{
        background-color:orange;
        width:450px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
          <div id="box3">
           <p>GREEN</p>
          </div>
          <div id="box4">
           <p>ORANGE</p>
          </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parent [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) container and nest the green and orange boxes in it as children to create a row using `display: flex`. Then adjust the `top` positioning for the bottom yellow box or make its height larger to occupy that empty space.

There is a little bit of unwanted extra space on the right side of the orange box and this goes away when the `border` from the blue box is removed. I see how you were using `border` on each box to substitute padding so I added some `padding` and everything aligns nicely.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

h1{
  position:relative;
  color:#89CFF0;
  font-family:arial;
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;  
}

.boxes{
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}

#box1{
  font-family:arial;
  /* border:1px solid red; */
  padding: .5rem 0;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1000px;
  top:40px;
  background-color:red;
}

#box2{
  font-family:arial;
  /* border:1px solid blue; */
  padding-top: .5rem;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1000px;
  height:150px;       
  top:40px;
  background-color:blue;
}

#box3{
  position:relative;
  font-family:arial;
  border:1px solid green;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  top:40px;
  float:left;
  background-color:green;
}

#box4{
  font-family:arial;
  border:1px solid orange;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  top:40px;
  float:left;
  background-color:orange;
}

#box5{
  font-family:arial;
  /* border:1px solid yellow; */
  padding: .5rem 0;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1000px;
  top:40px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1> The Box </h1>
<div class="boxes">
<div id="box1">
<p>RED</p>
</div>
<div id="box2">
<p>BLUE</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="box3">
<p>GREEN</p>
</div>
<div id="box4">
<p>ORANGE</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="box5">
<p>YELLOW</p>
</div>
</div>
```